# panTo() method interfering with bounce animation in Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm implementing a relatively simple Google Map that has various markers in it. I'm adding a listener to the marker such that it bounces up and down when clicked, and the map pans to it.

The expected behavior is that you click one pin and it bounces, you click it again and it stops. Also, if you click a pin and then click another one, the first stops bouncing and the second starts. Pretty intuitive.

What's happening, however, is that it stops working after two or three 'back and forths' between pins. I've narrowed down the culprit to the behavior of the map panning to the pin (panTo()). If I remove that, it works well.

The attached code reproduces the issue. If you comment the line with the panTo() method, you can see how it works fine.

Any thoughts on why this happens and how to fix it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
    let map;
    markers = [];

    positions = [
        {lat : 50.46818409999999, lng: 30.5252753},
        {lat : 50.46220959999999, lng: 30.5153674},
    ];

    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          center: { lat: 50.462, lng: 30.514 },
          zoom: 12,
        });
        dropmarkers();
    };

    function dropmarkers() {
        
        for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {

            window.setTimeout(() => {

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {lat: positions[i]['lat'], lng: positions[i]['lng']},
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                });

                markers.push(marker);

                marker.addListener("click", function () {
                    toggleAnimation(marker);
                    map.panTo({lat: positions[i]['lat'], lng: positions[i]['lng']});
                    map.setZoom(14);
                });

                marker.setMap(map);

            }, i * 200);
        };
    };

    function toggleAnimation(marker) {
        if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
            marker.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
            for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
                markers[j].setAnimation(null);
            }
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        };
    };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I´v noticed that even without map.panTo the issue seems to occur by fast clicking between the marker, realy strange. I experimented with setTimeouts wich seems to remoe the issue but leeds to a delayed animaton

Comment: @MartinGodzina where do you place the setTimeout? I tried on "marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);"
... but even 2000 wait time didn't do the trick ...

Comment: Looks similar to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38453974) for which Google did apprently *nothing* for the past 3 and a half years...

Comment: Looks related to this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/149537972) in Google's Public Issue Tracker, it was just recently fixed and stated that the fix will be included in the next version.